# Is there deep loading in subsonic?

Tags: subsonic, entity, data-access-layer

I am new in subsonic, and can't find the way to load data whith it's parents or childs data in one query. Is it possible in subsonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically no SubSonic 2 does not support deep loading. It is possible in SubSonic 3 using IQueryable however. See the following post for more:

[Subsonic Deeploads: Is This Supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770570/subsonic-deeploads-is-this-supported)

Answer (score -1):

You CAN do it with subsonic 2. Make a partial class with the same namespace and class name.

Then create a property that loads the data when it is called.